# Signal reflections on conductors at low frequencies where they are not transmission lines

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-resistance, wavelength, electrical-engineering

This question might be suited for the Electrical Engineering forum, but I think I might get more scientific explanation/discussion (rather than anecdotal) on this forum.

Is the reflection phenomenon common in RF work with unmatched source/load pairs also present at low frequencies? Or are the wavelengths so much longer than the physical conductor lengths that reflections do not matter?  Ie, are reflections strictly a function of wavelength relative to the conductors lengths?

Say for example I have a square wave fed into a pi-filter whose purpose is to extract a 100kHz fundamental (1/4 $\lambda$ = about half a mile).  The source and the pi-filter (and load) are unmatched. Does the power reflect back to the source?  the wavelength of the signal is much, much greater than the length of the conductors (about 10,000 times, for example, for 3" traces on a PCB)so I'm not sure how that would interfere with the source signal.  Perhaps the wavelengths of the higher harmonics would eventually be of "meaningful" lengths, but they should be at much lower power levels....

Would I see a distorted signal at the source due to a reflection from the pi-filter? Could the reflection  damage the source?  If the power is not reflected, is it absorbed by the filter? where does it go?

Since we can often "get away" without terminating signals in low frequency designs, I hardly ever worry about reflections. I've typically only worried about them at at high MHz signals, and when interfacing signals across backplanes, or long board interconnects.  But, it occurs to me that there should be reflections all the time.  How is it that they don't typically matter (in low frequency designs)?  How is it that sources driving unmatched loads are not "blown up" more often due to these reflections?

Comment: This question has also been posted on EE.SE: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/533007/6334.

Comment: yes...I just did....different audiences....

Comment: Not really. Cross-posting is discouraged unless you've given the question a couple of days on the first place you posted it and not gotten a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have a reflection from your termination but the real question is if it matters. Terminating a power amplifier with a sufficiently small impedance usually leads to sparks and smoke. If your connection to the termination is short, say less than $\lambda/10$, then the input impedance is very close to that of the termination so blowing up the generator is then up to the selection of the load but if the transmission line is long then the input impedance will strongly depend on its length and unpleasant surprises may abound, see the input impedance section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line
$$Z_{in}(\ell) = Z_0 \frac{Z_L + Z_0\mathfrak{j}\rm{tan}(\beta \ell)} {Z_0+Z_L \mathfrak{j}\rm{tan}(\beta \ell)}\\=Z_L\frac{1+(Z_0/Z_L)\mathfrak{j}\rm{tan}(\beta \ell)} {1+(Z_L/Z_0) \mathfrak{j}\rm{tan}(\beta \ell)}$$
Now let $\beta \ell <0.1$ you have $|\rm{tan}(\beta \ell)|<0.1$ and assume also that your load impedance is, say, $Z_0/10 <|Z_L| < 10Z_L$, then you will also have that $|Z_{in}| \gg 0$ and no worries; the shorter the length $\ell$ is the closer $Z_{in}$ is to $Z_L$ irrespective of the wave impedance $Z_0$.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Not sure I follow.  When you say,"terminating a power amplifier with a sufficiently small impedance usually leads to sparks and smoke..." -- is that because of reflections or because excessive current draw?   Also, if I understand you, so Zin is close to ZL due to long wavelengths and short conductor lengths, so the source sees practically ZL.  What does that do to the reflected voltage ultimately reaching the source?

Comment: a sufficiently small impedance is almost a short circuit, and shorting the terminals of a power amplifier will draw a large current, burn the output stage, etc.

Comment: if $Z_L\ne Z_0$ you always get reflection that depends on the length, the questions will the reflection be a problem? If a $Z_L$ termination is ok for your amp and the line is short then the load that the amp sees is $Z_{in} \approx Z_L$, and that is what you want and any reflection will not be a problem.

Comment: then the result of the reflection is that the load sees a voltage drop of the open circuit voltage from the source impedance on the load: $V_{in} \approx V_{source} Z_{in}/(Z_{source}+Z_{in})$

Comment: Ok..I follow what the load sees. But what does the source see?  I mean, there is a reflected wave going back to the source is there not?  what does that look like at the source?  I'm envisioning in some scenarios the reflected wave driving against the source voltage.  Under some conditions, I'd expect this to cause damage to the source (force the source to sink current, ie voltage right after the source impedance is larger than the driven source voltage. or like you mentioned, source excessive current.  Am I misinterpreting what is meant by reflection?  Thank you, I appreciate the discussion.

Comment: see my comment right above yours, the source sees $\approx Z_L$ on which the voltage is just $V_{in}$, just as any voltage divider - that is the result of reflection from starting at $V_{source}$ and ending at $V_{in}\approx V_L$

Comment: oh-oh-oh....I misunderstood your previous  comment! I see now what you were doing.  Got it, thanks!! very helpful. .

Comment: I just reread this response of yours and it took me a while to understand it again.  It would be great to include a picture to identify Vin, Vsource, Zin, Zsource, Zl, Z0, etc...... Could you perhaps edit your answer and include a simple diagram? Thank you.

Comment: +1 hyportnex ---thank you. Zin is still different than Zs...so shouldn't there should be reflections there again?   Also, I don't see how there could ever could be a voltage at Vin that is greater than Vsource;    If Zin is large, Vin will approximate Vsource, and if Zin is low, then Vin will be less than Vsource.  So, under what conditions  would I destroy the source, not due to loading , but because of the reflected energy being too great?

Comment: (1) you always get a reflection at the source if $Z_s \ne Z_0$ because the wave reflected from the load is still travelling on $Z_0$ line and it sees a load of $Z_s$ for the voltage has impedance $0$. (2) think of an LC circuit driven by the source $V_s, Z_s$, can the voltage on the LC at its resonance be larger than $|V_s|$ ?

Comment: so, if $Z_s$ is small, and the reflected signal is large, then the source would shunt all that energy and could potentially be destroyed.  So, current would flow from Vin to Vsource, and it is current that could potentially damage the source.  And this suggests that for current to flow into the source, Vin would have to be larger than Vsource.

Comment: btw, I tried upvoting your answer, but I don't have a high enough reputation to do so....

Comment: no problem, am glad to help